# Access set's bounds in multiple requests - overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have 2 overpass requests sent in a signle call to overpass server as follows :

```
[out:json];

(

way["highway"~"."](around:150,SOME_LAT,SOME_LNG);

)->.bounds_highways;

out geom 1;

out count;

(

  way[highway~"^(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary|tertiary|(motorway|trunk|primary|secondary)_link)$"](bbox.bounds_highways)->.major_intersections;

  way[highway~"^(unclassified|residential|living_street|service)$"](bbox.bounds_highways)->.minor_intersections;

  node(w.major_intersections)(w.minor_intersections);

);

out geom 1;
```

In the second request part I'm trying to access the bounds field returned by the first part without any success.

Is there a way to do it?

Thank's.